# How to change png image file type size from 940x940 to 512x512 and from Bit depth 8 to Bit depth 32 like in Paint?

Tags: c#, winforms

When i'm editing in Paint png image the png image is size 940x940 Bit depth 8 then i'm changing in Paint the image size to 512x512 and save it as png. now the new png image is size 512x512 Bit depth 32.

this is what i want to do but in the code instead in Paint. to take png images change the images size to 512x512 and save them again as png but with Bith depth 32.

so each image in the end should be : png , 512x512, bit depth 32

what i'm doing now is :

```
List<string> images = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\Tuesday 01.31.2023 at 04.42 AM", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .ToList();

            Bitmap bmptest = new Bitmap(images[0]);
            Bitmap bmp = Create24bpp(bmptest, new Size(512, 512));
            bmp.Save(@"d:\resized123456.png");
            bmp.Dispose();
            bmptest.Dispose();
```

the method Create24bpp :

```
public static Bitmap Create24bpp(System.Drawing.Image image, Size size)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height,
                System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            return bmp;
        }
```

but what i'm getting is black new image . it's 512,512 png and bit depth 24 but black.
i want to get the original image just 512x512 and bit depth 24 like it is when changing the size and saving in paint.

i tried what i described above in the question body.

```
List<string> images = Directory.GetFiles(@"d:\Downloaded Images\Radar\Tuesday 01.31.2023 at 04.42 AM", "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                .ToList();

            Bitmap bmptest = new Bitmap(images[0]);
            Bitmap bmp = Create24bpp(bmptest, new Size(512, 512));
            bmp.Save(@"d:\resized123456.png");
            bmp.Dispose();
            bmptest.Dispose();
```

even if i'm changing the format to : Format32bppArgb in the Create24bpp method the result image is still  black. png , 512x512 , bit depth 32 but black !